# RavenDb: RavenJObject.ToObject<T>() lost Id

Tags: ravendb

I have an entity type:

```
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And my Index:

```
public class LogIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Log>
{
    public LogIndex()
    {
        Map = xs => from x in xs
                    select new
                    {
                        x.Id,
                        x.Action,
                        x.Message 
                    };
    }
}
```

Then I can use them to store logs and I can use `context.Query<Log, LogIndex>().Where(x => x.Action== "GetString").ToList()` to get logs.

And then I try to use Commands to query my logs:

```
QueryResult queryResult = context.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Query("LogIndex", new IndexQuery
    {
        Query = "Action:(GetString)"
    });
Log log = queryResult.Results.First().ToObject<Log>();
```

My problem is:
The log which is returned by `ToObject<Log>()` lose it's Id property's value(it is 0). But it's Action and Message property's value are not lost..

Is using `RavenJObject.ToObject<T>()` the right way to get query result(entities) ? If it is, what's wrong with my code? If it is not, which is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't the proper way to go about it.
To start with, you are using very low level API, and should make use of the session for this.

If you'll use the session, it will take care of setting the ID properly.